# How to append an 1-D numpy array to a multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy array, one with a shape of 10*12 and another one with shape of 1*12. I'd like the final shape to be 11*12. I want to append the second array to the first one. However  I always get a dimensionality mismatch error from numpy.

```
import numpy

left_padding = []
[left_padding.append(numpy.zeros(12)) for i in range(10)]
left_padding = numpy.asarray(left_padding)
frame = numpy.reshape(numpy.arange(12), (1, 123))
numpy.append(left_padding, frame, axis = 0)
```

This throws the following error.

```
values = ravel(values)
axis = arr.ndim-1
return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

However, if I append a 5*10 dimensional array to left_padding, it does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: What do you want the final shape to be?

Comment: Use [`row_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.row_stack.html) : `np.row_stack((left_padding,frame))`?

Comment: Please provide,small (shape = (3,4)), example inputs and expected result.  I'm unfamiliar with the notation ```10*12``` for an ndarray shape - did you mean ```(10,12)```?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. numpy.row_stack((left_padding, frame)) works.

Comment: @wwii, I'd like the final shape to be 11*12. The solution Divakar provided worked.

Comment: I was thinking ```np.vstack```.